# is it okay to assume my commands in use are exist by default with almost all distributions

Tags: linux, development, portability

I'm maintaining a small USB device driver code for Linux.
This is a user mode code so , there are places that we need to find what is the version of `libudev` so and etc. So the only way that I came up with , assumes that there are certain UNIX commands already available by default in almost all distributions that we are going to provide our binaries. Few of those commands are as follows.

```
head
cut
ldconfig
pkg-config
```

What I'm asking is, is it safe to assume that ? that those commands are exists in almost all Linux distributions?

We will surely have issues with porting this to *nix, like `MacOs` or `GNU Hrud`. But we are targeting the Linux distributions only not even BSD.

Comment: Even on systems that use pkg-config, it may be absent.

Comment: So what about other distributions other than debain ? But ubuntu do have that function and I'm currently developing with ubuntu. So code would need some modification only to handle pkg-config dependency right ?

Comment: @cutrightjm Um... What? `pkg-config` is used in Debian, it's just not installed by default (it's a development tool, unnecessary for most users).

Comment: @StephenKitt "... assumes that there are certain UNIX commands available by default.." I took that to mean already installed.

Comment: We can't force our users to install something manually like that. Neither  I can prompt in our driver installation script. So then any way to do this without pkg-config --modversion to get the version of libudev?

Comment: Don't assume anything, check, and if missing prompt about it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry about this, unless there are really many dependencies.

The porters/packagers in the teams know how to handle build-time and runtime dependencies. And the tools you mentioned might not be installed on all systems (especially `pkg-config`), but are all pretty common and well understood.

You should document the dependencies and that's all these people need to know.